# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova: Code Sign Error on Xcode 8 and iOS 10 Cordova Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I use VS2015 to develop Cordova.
Recently I update Xcode and get the following error when build ios

> Signing for "BlankCordovaApp10" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

And then I saw this solution [Code Sign Error on Xcode 8 and iOS 10 Cordova Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501020/code-sign-error-on-xcode-8-and-ios-10-cordova-project)

But after following the instruction in it, the following 3 steps, the same error still occurred.

1. cordova platform remove ios
2. cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git
3. update build.json as the following (modify my team id as XXXX)
   [image]

Could someone help shed some light how to apply it in VS2015 cordova?

You can repro it once you update Xcode in Mac and build ios app in VS2015 cordova.

Thanks.

Comment: I personally just use the Xcode to build the iOS app. I run "cordova clean ios" then "cordova prepare ios". After that I use Xcode to build and publish. Xcode 8 changed the signing process. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic) for some details. I had to uncheck and check the "Automatically manage signing" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. 
I currently work around by copy the iOS folder under platform to Mac and use Xcode to open it and deploy. 

Hope Microsoft guys who support remotebuild can see and check this issue.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to copy the iOS folder from the PC? Running `cordova platform add ios` and `cordova prepare ios` will create it on the Mac side. I only copy the **www** folder and **config.xml** over.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a cordova-ios version before 4.3.0 take a look here: [Cordova builds with Xcode 8](https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html)

I have solved with the hook reported in link above ([this one](https://gist.github.com/dpogue/186b6c1827363c48d644b0d59e91bc28)).

> **Development Team**
>
> **Cordova-iOS 3.4.0** allows specifying a developmentTeam in build.json, which will be used to populate the **DEVELOPMENT_TEAM** setting. You do not need the hook if you're using **Cordova-iOS 4.3.0**.
>
> If you're using an older version, I've written a hook that you can add to your project. Save that file in your hooks folder, and reference it in your **config.xml**:
>
> ```
>  <platform name="ios">   
>   <hook type="before_compile">
>  <src="hooks/xcode8.js" /> </platform>
> ```