# Visual Studio + Cordova Remotebuild failed Error: 65

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, cordova

until today I could easily build iOS apps from my Windows-PC with remotebuild to my Mac and build it on the connected iPad on my Mac. But now i updated all devices (Mac, iPad) and suddenly it stopped working. When i want to build in Visual Studio i get this message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/grafikschulung/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/877/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,memoxx.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,memoxx,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/grafikschulung/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/877/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/grafikschulung/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/877/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch: {1} Katalog C:\Users\m.hüttl\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Katalog - Kopie\Katalog\MDAVSCLI 1

When I copy the project-folder to my Mac and import it into xCode and choose a development-team and build it from xCode it works perfect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe until Cordova CLI is updated for Visual Sudio with the Xcode 8 changes you will have this issue.  Darryl Pogue did write a hook if you want to follow his instructions on his [site](https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html) which might fix the development team issue you are having.

There are a couple other suggestions on the following Stack Overflow page that might give you other options such as changing settings in the Xcode project.

[Code Sign Error on Xcode 8 and iOS 10 Cordova Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501020/code-sign-error-on-xcode-8-and-ios-10-cordova-project)