# Testing Xcode project on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to test my project on my iPhone but I get this error:

> "Signing for "Baseball Simulator" requires a development team. Select
>   a development team in the project editor."

as well as this one:

> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS
>   10.3'

It was working before, but now I am looking everywhere and it seem like I have to pay. Is there anyway to do it for free?

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Signing++requires+a+development+team.+Select+a+development+team+in+the+project+editor) before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Sign Error on Xcode 8 and iOS 10 Cordova Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501020/code-sign-error-on-xcode-8-and-ios-10-cordova-project)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to pay. Your personal dev team should be enough, and that comes with every free dev account.

Click the checkbox to automatically manage signing, make sure your personal team is selected in the drop down, and if that doesn't work, remove your account from Xcode and re-add it.

You may need to modify the bundle identifier if working with a tutorial or example project. Make it unique to you.